# Detect time out in asp.net page and redirect to login

Tags: asp.net, .net, session

I am using the code below in the Global.asax to detect timeout in an asp.net application

```
 protected void Session_Start(object src, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Context.Session != null && Context.Session.IsNewSession)
        {
            string sCookieHeader = Request.Headers["Cookie"];
            if (null != sCookieHeader && sCookieHeader.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0)
                    Response.Redirect("~/TimeoutMessage.aspx");
        }
    }
```

The above code works well, however, when I click on a hyperlink on the timeoutmessage.aspx page which is supposed to redirect the user the login, it just keep redirecting itself to the timeout page.

Comment: Have you done any debugging in Visual Studio? What is the value of sCookieHeader? What is the return value from sCookieHeader.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to check this is the Oninit event in page. Please create a base page inheriting from System.Web.UI.Page and override the oninit event. Put your code there. Then inherit the page from this base page. It will work fine.

```
public class BasePage:System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Context.Session != null && Context.Session.IsNewSession)
            {
                string sCookieHeader = Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                if (null != sCookieHeader && sCookieHeader.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0)
                    Response.Redirect("~/TimeoutMessage.aspx");
            }

            base.OnInit(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am still facing the same issues the time is detected and redirect to the "Timeoutmessage.aspx" page,on the "Timeoutmessage.aspx page the hyperlink to redirect to the login just keeps redirecting to the Timeoutmessage.aspx page

Comment: Hi Login.aspx should not inherit the BasePage. That will fix the problem